# Best Wordpress plugin for transferring Excel/Google Sheets data into a table?

Tags: excel, wordpress

I'm currently making a news website which will have results in a table format from mass-start cycling races displayed in articles. At the moment it involves manually inputting data into an HTML script, but it's a very labour-intensive process and I'm wondering if there is a faster/easier way to transfer the data.

Comment: I don't think plugin recommendations are on topic, sorry, either here or on the WordPress stack exchange - they'd count as opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin for everything: https://wpdatatables.com/documentation/creating-wpdatatables/creating-wpdatatables-from-csv/

But tbh, CSVs are literally just a list of **comma-separated values**, and they look like:

```
col1,col2,col3
col1,col2,col3
...
```

And you can do this yourself without a plugin if you can style the table yourself:

```js
const CSV = `John,Doe,120 jefferson st.,Riverside, NJ, 08075
Jack,McGinnis,220 hobo Av.,Phila, PA,09119
"John ""Da Man""",Repici,120 Jefferson St.,Riverside, NJ,08075
Stephen,Tyler,"7452 Terrace ""At the Plaza"" road",SomeTown,SD, 91234
,Blankman,,SomeTown, SD, 00298
"Joan ""the bone"", Anne",Jet,"9th, at Terrace plc",Desert City,CO,00123`;

const table = document.getElementById('csvTable');

let rows = CSV.split('\n').map(row => row.split(',')),
    i = 0;                                // row counter

for (let row of rows) {

  let newRow = table.insertRow(i++),      // add new row at i
      j = 0;                              // init col counter
  
  for (let cell of row) {
    let newCell = newRow.insertCell(j++); // add new cell at i
    newCell.innerHTML = cell;             // set cell contents
  }
  
}
```

```css
th, td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<table id="csvTable">
  <thead>My Parsed CSV</thead>
</table>
```